# one-many realtionship update with changed table format

Tags: laravel-5.6

if there are two tables `show` and `show_detail` and `show` table has fields like 'id','show_name'(array) like ["show_1","show_2","famous_show_12"]  and `show_detail` has fields like 'show_id','show_name','show_ids'..then how to update `show_detail` table with update in table `show` using one-many relationship.
i have tried using updateRich() method but fail.

Comment: how fail? can describe more? like what error you get.. also your table structure is not exactly clear.. sorry..

Comment: i have confusion related to how can i do it so i am not able to perform it thorughly..if u can help please do.

Comment: could you share your model please? also what laravel version you are using? i cant find `updateRich` on the docs..

Answer (score 0):

Use Like It :-

```
$id = 123;
$show = 'test show';
DB::table('show')->where('id', $id)->update(['show_name' => $show]);
DB::table('show_detail')->whereIn('show_ids', [1, 2])->update(['show_name' => $show]);
```

Comment: how can i perform it using repository..and method updateRich()?